# How to enable my search method when the text is begin deleted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using my "searching" method in order to filter data in recyclerView according to EditText input changes, it works fine but when the text is deleted(partially) nothing is being filtered.

**My searching method:**

```
//a method to filter the question list search
private void searching(){
    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int il, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            for (int iterator = 0; iterator < filterForSearch.size(); iterator++) {
                //if what i searched have a part of question title - do not filter else filter
                if (!filterForSearch.get(iterator).get("title").toString().contains(search.getText().toString())  ){
                    filterForSearch.remove(iterator);
                }
            }
            //set the adapter with the data that the user searched
            setQuestionsAdapter(filterForSearch);
            filterForSearch = cloudData;
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            // when the user delete his search - show him the questions again
            if(search.getText().toString().equals("")){
                pullData();
            }
    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems that you saving only the filtered result and because of this when ever you delete the text you have less text to filter through.
If you are filtering from the database to get all the result I would recommend to search with filter for each text change, this way you will filter from all of your database (you will not need to get all of it in to the device in the first place which is wrong to do), and second you will get your result's when ever you change the text (on delete too).